# formatting strings to iterate over dataframe

Tags: pandas, loops, text, format, special-characters

**Background:**

I have the following code to make a dataframe from a list:

```
l = ['the cat meows',
     'the dog barks',
     'the bird chirps']
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Text'])
```

**Output:**

```
          Text
0   the cat meows
1   the dog barks
2   the bird chirps
```

**Desired Output:**

```
          Text     Animal   
0   the cat meows   cat
1   the dog barks   dog
2   the bird chirps bird
```

**Approach:**

I attempt to get the **Desired Output** using the following code:

```
#create list of animal names
animal_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']

#extract names from 'Text' column using the names in 'animal_list' 
#and create a new column containing extracted 'Text' names
df['Sound'] = df['Animal'].str.extract(r"(%s)"% animal_list)
```

**Problem:**

However, I get the following when I do so:

```
            Text    Animal
0   the cat meows   t
1   the dog barks   t
2   the bird chirps t
```

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired output?

Comment: What is the logic here. Do we need to use your `animal_list` or is the middle word everytime?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. My goals are the following: 1) extract names from 'Text' column 2) using the names in 'animal_list'  3) create a new column containing extracted 'Text' names

Comment: And yes, the words in `animal_list` are needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using the `animal_list` with `str.extract`

We can use `Series.str.extract` here and pass it your `animal_list` delimited by a `|` which is the `or` operator in regex:

```
df['Animal'] = df['Text'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(animal_list)})")
```

**Or** if you have python < 3.5 you cannot use *f-string*

We can use @Mike's answer from the comments

```
df['Animal'] = df['Animal'].str.extract(r"({})".format("|".join(animal_list)))
```

**Output**

```
              Text Animal
0    the cat meows    cat
1    the dog barks    dog
2  the bird chirps   bird
```

## Getting the middle word with `str.split`

```
df['Animal'] = df['Text'].str.split().str[1]
```

**Output**

```
              Text Animal
0    the cat meows    cat
1    the dog barks    dog
2  the bird chirps   bird
```

Comment: Sniped me! `df['Sound'] = df['Animal'].str.extract(r"({})".format("|".join(animal_list)))`

Comment: Thanks for the addition, added your solution in the answer as well @Mike